# Microsoft Office - Powerpoint: How to play multiple audio clips concurrently on click of slide?

Tags: audio, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to set up a slide so that three audio clips will play sequentially on-click, each in turn. I know you can set the trigger to start playing 'on click' but this only works on click of the audio object itself or any other object on the slide, not on the slide itself. I want to be able to just click the slide and have Audio 1 play, then click it again and have Audio 2 play, then click again and have Audio 3 play.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a rectangle that covers the entire slide.

Then in the animation pane, select the first of the sounds, choose the Timing option, then click Triggers.

Choose "Start effect on click of:" and pick the rectangle you just drew from the dropdown list.  If your slide is fairly complex, you may want to rename the rectangle using the Selection pane first, so it's easier to recognize in the dropdown list.

Finally, make the rectangle invisible by giving it no outline and setting its fill to 99 or 100% transparent.

Now the sound will play when you click anywhere on the slide.